Measuring the current in a LL circuit with a AC source, doesn't work, i always get this error when i start the simulation, Proteus ISIS

When i click to simulate, it always shows up with this error and it fails
'''[SPICE] singular matrix: check node #L1#branch.
▲[SPICE] singular matrix, check node #L1 #branch.
▲[SPICE] Gmin stepping failed
[SPICE] singular matrix check node #L1#branch
▲[SPICE] Source step [0 of 120) failed: source factor = 0.0000
▲[SPICE] (null)'''
I suspect the reason is because i'm trying without a resistor, when i put the resistor it works fine, what could be triggering this error message? Could you guys help me?

It's singular because any solution with an arbitrary constant current added to it is also a solution.

You can't connect an ideal inductor as a load to an ideal voltage source as it becomes nearly impossible for the simulator to solve.
Introduce a parasitic resistance such as:

A physical resistor in series (e.g. between the inductors and the source)
A non-zero DC resistance for at least one of the inductors (inductor should have such property)
A non-zero output resistance for the source (again, voltage source should have such property)

I don't know if Proteus defines a DC resistance for inductors by default (e.g. 1 mOhm) but in any case, it's better to define manually.

A DC resistance would be the generic one, right?

@fireBreaker_2007 I don't understand what you mean by "generic" but you can add a physical resistance in series, or change the DC resistance parameter of the inductor (I think it should include one) or change the output resistance parameter of the source (again, I think it should include one).

When selecting the resistor, i selected the generic one, on the categories, from Proteus
